Maximizing an exponential sum
For a fixed $m$, let $y_1,\dots, y_m \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Let $D$ be a given subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then, consider the function
\begin{equation}
f(y_1,\dots,y_m)\triangleq \max_{\{z_j\}_{j=1}^m\subset D} \exp\left(-\sum_{j=1}^m\lVert y_j -z_j\rVert_{R^{-1}}^2\right)
\end{equation}
where $\lVert y_j -z_j\rVert_{R^{-1}}^2\triangleq (y_j-z_j)' R^{-1} (y_j-z_j)$ is the squared Mahalanobis distance between $y_j$ and $z_j$ (weighted by a given symmetric and positive definite matrix $R$). I'm not sure if I'm correct or not, but I suspect that
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f(y_1,\dots,y_m)&\triangleq \exp\left(-\sum_{j=1}^m\lVert y_j -z_j^*\rVert_{R^{-1}}^2\right)\\
z_j^* &\triangleq \arg \min_{z\in D} \lVert y_j-z\rVert_{R^{-1}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
In words, I believe that for each $y_j$ the relative $z_j$ is the point $z$ in $D$ that minimizes the Mahalanobis distance from $y_j$. This because the exponential splits in the product of $m$ exponentials, then each factor should be maximized by considering the closest possible couple $y_j,z_j$.
I don't know why, but I'm not 100% sure about my conjecture.
Question
Is my conjecture right?

It looks fine to me. As you observed, the problem boils down to solving $\max_{z_i \in D} \exp(-|y_j - z_j|{R^{-1}}^2)$ separately for each $j$. (Although, do be sure to impose some regularity assumptions on $D$ to ensure $\arg \min{z \in D} |y_j - z|_{R^{-1}}$ exists.)

My doubt arises from the following observation: what if we completely ignore some $y_j$ and we "assign multiple neighbohrs" to some other $y_{k\neq j}$? Can this strategy be optimal or we are forced to make a 1-1 association between the $y$s and the $z$s?

Sorry, I don't quite understand the above observation you mentioned. Perhaps you could illustrate with a concrete example?
